# ImageMagick: `convert` is modifying png24 to png8, any solution?

Tags: imagemagick, png

I am converting some high-res iPhone images to low-res with batch processing using ImageMagick. I simply run the following:

`convert image@2x.png -resize '50%' image.png`

The problem is using `pngcheck`, it appears that the original @2x file is 32bit (where 8bits are an alpha channel) and in the down sized version, that is stripped away.

pngcheck output (before convert):

OK: image@2x.png (85x81, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 94.6%).

pngcheck output (after convert):

OK: image.png (43x41, 8-bit palette+trns, non-interlaced, 4.8%).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use specifier to force output format.

`convert image@2x.png -resize '50%' PNG32:image.png`